# ImportError - from qiskit import BasicAer

Tags: python, importerror, dlopen, alloc, qiskit

I used
conda create --name qc-26 --clone base;
conda activate qc-26;
jupyter notebook

Whenever I ran,

from qiskit import BasicAer

I received the following error messages

```
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/QC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweedledum/_tweedledum.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _aligned_alloc
  Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/envs/QC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweedledum/_tweedledum.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /opt/anaconda3/envs/QC/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweedledum/_tweedledum.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

Below is the qiskit information on my iMAC, version 10.13.6
{'qiskit-terra': '0.17.4', 'qiskit-aer': '0.8.2', 'qiskit-ignis': '0.6.0', 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.13.1', 'qiskit-aqua': '0.9.1', 'qiskit': '0.26.1', 'qiskit-nature': None, 'qiskit-finance': None, 'qiskit-optimization': None, 'qiskit-machine-learning': '0.2.0'}

Comment: The bug is known and upstream is working on it https://github.com/boschmitt/tweedledum/issues/159